# Gazetteer Database for ANNIE / GATE

Tags: gate

I'm learning to use GATE / ANNIE / JAPE and I'm wondering whether there is a database somewhere of gazetteer lists. ANNIE's default lists are great, but obviously they don't provide lists for everything.

I'm looking for a list of colleges and universities. I could easily build one myself, but it occurred to me that, like the colleges list, most gazetteer lists are likely to be reused. So it seems like there should be a database of such lists somewhere. Does anyone know of one? (I Googled quickly but didn't find anything.)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the data available at : http://wiki.dbpedia.org

Answer (score 0):

Some more:

-OpenCalais

http://www.opencalais.com/

GATE Plugin: Tagger_OpenCalais

-Zemanta

GATE Plugin: Tagger_Zemanta

-Lupedia

http://lupedia.ontotext.com/

GATE Plugin: Tagger_Lupedia